# Liferay : Configuring Multiple Spring MVC Portlets in one liferay plugin project with one common controller and multiple landing pages

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, liferay-6

I am developing Spring MVC based portlet in liferay. Basically I want to configure and maintain 2 or 3 portlets in a single liferay project itself. Can some on guide me with the configuration required for the same. Like config code for portlet.xml, spring config and web config (if its required). I just need to configure a default controller for all my portlets so each will land in different landing page.

Does anybody know how to config these portlets ? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to config multiple portlets in one .war file. This is pretty simple and all you need to do is properly configure them in few xml files. Below I have prepared for you few config files required to define 3 portlets in 6.2 liferay version:

**liferay-display.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE display PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Display 6.2.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-display_6_2_0.dtd">

<display>
    <category name="category.amg">
        <portlet id="first-portlet" />
        <portlet id="second-portlet" />
        <portlet id="third-portlet" />
    </category>
</display>
```

**liferay-portlet.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE liferay-portlet-app PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Portlet Application 6.2.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_6_2_0.dtd">

<liferay-portlet-app>
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>first-portlet</portlet-name>
        <icon>/icon.png</icon>
        <instanceable>true</instanceable>
        <private-request-attributes>false</private-request-attributes>
        <requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
        <render-weight>1000</render-weight>
    </portlet>
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>second-portlet</portlet-name>
        <icon>/icon.png</icon>
        <instanceable>true</instanceable>
        <private-request-attributes>false</private-request-attributes>
        <requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
        <render-weight>1000</render-weight>
    </portlet>
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>third-portlet</portlet-name>
        <icon>/icon.png</icon>
        <instanceable>false</instanceable>
        <private-request-attributes>false</private-request-attributes>
        <requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
        <render-weight>1000</render-weight>
    </portlet>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        <role-link>Administrator</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>guest</role-name>
        <role-link>Guest</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        <role-link>Power User</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
        <role-link>User</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
</liferay-portlet-app>
```

**portlet.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<portlet-app version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd">
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>first-portlet</portlet-name>
        <display-name>first-portlet</display-name>
        <portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>contextConfigLocation</name>
            <value>/WEB-INF/context/first-portlet.xml</value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <name>check-auth-token</name>
            <value>false</value>
        </init-param>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
            <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
            <portlet-mode>edit</portlet-mode>
        </supports>
        <supported-locale>pl</supported-locale>
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
        <resource-bundle>portlets-names.first-portlet</resource-bundle>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>first portlet</title>
            <short-title>first</short-title>
            <keywords>first</keywords>
        </portlet-info>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>guest</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
    </portlet>
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>second-portlet</portlet-name>
        <display-name>second-portlet</display-name>
        <portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>contextConfigLocation</name>
            <value>/WEB-INF/context/second-portlet.xml</value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <name>check-auth-token</name>
            <value>false</value>
        </init-param>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
            <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
            <portlet-mode>edit</portlet-mode>
        </supports>
        <supported-locale>pl</supported-locale>
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
        <resource-bundle>portlets-names.second</resource-bundle>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>second portlet</title>
            <short-title>second</short-title>
            <keywords>second</keywords>
        </portlet-info>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>guest</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
    </portlet>
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>third-portlet</portlet-name>
        <display-name>third-portlet</display-name>
        <portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>contextConfigLocation</name>
            <value>/WEB-INF/context/third-portlet.xml</value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <name>check-auth-token</name>
            <value>false</value>
        </init-param>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
            <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
        </supports>
        <supported-locale>pl</supported-locale>
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
        <resource-bundle>portlets-names.third</resource-bundle>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>third portlet</title>
            <short-title>third</short-title>
            <keywords>third</keywords>
        </portlet-info>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>guest</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
    </portlet>

</portlet-app>
```

Also make sure to add context files for each of portlet defined in **portlet.xml**

This is the tree, how it should look like in the end for 3 portlets

```
.
├── main
│   ├── java
..... your java sources.....
.....................
│   ├── resources
│   │   ├── first-portlet_en_US.properties
│   │   ├── first-portlet_pl_PL.properties
│   │   ├── first-portlet.properties
│   │   ├── second-friendly-url-routes.xml
│   │   ├── second-portlet_en_US.properties
│   │   ├── second-portlet_pl_PL.properties
│   │   ├── second-portlet.properties
│   │   ├── third-friendly-url-routes.xml
│   │   ├── third-portlet_en_US.properties
│   │   ├── third-portlet_pl_PL.properties
│   │   ├── third-portlet.properties
│   │   ├── portlet.properties
│   │   ├── portlets-names
│   │   │   ├── first_en_US.properties
│   │   │   ├── first_pl_PL.properties
│   │   │   ├── first.properties
│   │   │   ├── second_en_US.properties
│   │   │   ├── second_pl_PL.properties
│   │   │   ├── second.properties
│   │   │   ├── third_en_US.properties
│   │   │   ├── third_pl_PL.properties
│   │   │   ├── third.properties
│   │   └── resource-actions
│   │       └── default.xml
│   └── webapp
│       ├── css
│       │   └── third-uploader.css
│       ├── icon.png
│       └── WEB-INF
│           ├── context
│           │   ├── first-portlet.xml
│           │   ├── common.xml
│           │   ├── second-portlet.xml
│           │   └── third-portlet.xml
│           ├── jsp
│           │   ├── first
│           │   │   ├── article-details-view.jsp
│           │   │   ├── first-edit.jsp
│           │   │   └── first-view.jsp
│           │   ├── second
│           │   │   ├── second-details-view.jsp
│           │   │   ├── second-edit.jsp
│           │   │   └── second-list-view.jsp
│           │   ├── init.jsp
│           │   └── third
│           │       ├── third-filter-view.jsp
│           │       ├── third-more-page-view.jsp
│           │       ├── third-view.jsp
│           │       └── uploader
│           │           └── uploader-view.jsp
│           ├── liferay-display.xml
│           ├── liferay-plugin-package.properties
│           ├── liferay-portlet.xml
│           ├── log4j.properties
│           ├── portlet.xml
│           └── web.xml
└── test
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing some resources with you may be they help you. If you still can't get it I will share one of my example.

http://www.opensource-techblog.com/2012/09/spring-mvc-portlet-in-liferay.html

http://www.opensource-techblog.com/2012/09/spring-mvc-portlet-in-liferay.html